# Erros na personalização da ListView

Tags: android

Bem, eu estive tentando personalizar uma ListView em meu projeto, terminei e estava tudo certo. Porém apareceu um erro de API informando que a API minima que eu usei era muito baixa. Usei a opção de correção do eclipse sem saber se funcionária, o erro sumiu e então tentei executar o APK. Infelizmente ele não abria e o sistema informava que o aplicativo parou.

Imaginei que o responsável por isso fosse aquele erro de API. Tentei criar outro projeto com uma API minima maior, porém ao copiar o código diversos erros apareceram. Os GETs que eu usei em uma das classes deixaram de funcionar sem motivo aparente. Estou com erro na ActionBarActivity em outra classe. Ao importar, ela fica com o risco amarelo embaixo e deixa de funcionar, assim como o import da mesma. Caso eu retire o import, ela fica vermelha. Também e não sei ao certo qual o motivo. Segue as screenshots das das classes que apresentam erros.

[image: Erros de get]
[image: Erros na ActionBarActivity]

Comment: Está com risco porque está depreciada, veja direto da [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html).

Comment: `ArrayList` está em amarelo porque não está em uso, a importação foi feita, mas a classe não foi usada no código.

Comment: Quanto ao `itemPosicao`, essa classe `Item` foi você quem criou? Se sim, adicione ela também na pergunta. Adicione também qual mensagem a IDE mostra na variavel com risco vermelho.

Comment: Pois bem Diego, eu entendo que o risco amarelo implica que não estou usando, mas porque daquele risco no meio da "ActionBarActivity"? 

Este é o erro dos GETs. http://prntscr.com/95dyqa 

E sim, fui eu quem criou a classe Item. Segue o código. http://prntscr.com/95e07u

Comment: Veja meu primeiro comentário, nele está a resposta do porquê da classe "ActionBarActivity" está com o risco. Sugiro você a postar o código da classe item aqui também, e o erro que está aparecendo no sublihando vermelho.

Comment: Eu postei acima as screenshots hospedadas pelo lightshot. Infelizmente o comentário remove a formatação do código e fica confuso. Em todo caso, a mensagem de erro dos get é: The method getX() is undefined for the type ClipData.Item

Comment: Você pode colar o código na pergunta, depois selecione todo o código e clique na opção `{}` que ele aparece formatado.

Answer (score 1):

O risco é um aviso de que a classe que você está usando está obsoleta, isso pode ser confirmado na propria documentação da classe [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html). Você pode usar a classe [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) como substituta, desde que você não faça uso de algum recurso critico da classe obsoleta, ai o recomendado é você revisar seu código, de forma a adaptar as funcionalidades para a nova classe.

Quanto ao erro os métodos da variável `itemPosicao`, pode ser porque você deve estar usando a classe do android tambem se chama [ClipData.item](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/ClipData.Item.html). Cheque se você importou corretamente a sua classe custom `item` ao invés da classe do android, e se a variavel `itemPosicao` é do tipo da sua classe `item` ou do tipo da classe nativa do android.

Como sugestão, você poderia alterar o nome da sua custom classe, evitando que ela conflite com classes nativas, usando nomes que definam melhor que tipo de item se trata. Um exemplo no próprio android, é o `menu` possui `menuItem`.

Referencias:

[**Documentação Android**](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/packages.html)

Comment: Bem, como resolver o problema da classe estar depreciada (se é que é um problema)? 

Sobre o ClipData.Item, eu percebi que tinha um import dele, apaguei e os erros sumiram, porém uma série de erros apareceram na classe ListaItemActivity.  

The constructor ClipData.Item(int, int, String, String) is undefined. 
   The constructor ListaAdapterItem(ListaItemActivity, ArrayList<ClipData.Item>) is undefined

Comment: @RodrigoP. atualizei a resposta. Não remova a importação. Faça o que eu citei na resposta em relação a variavel `itemPosicao`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Diego. Consegui resolver todos os erros apenas fazendo essa pequena alteração, nunca imaginaria isso sozinho. Porém um último erro apareceu, novamente um erro de API. 

Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Activity#onCreateView. Qual a solução mais viável para este pequeno erro?

Comment: @RodrigoP. Essa classe nova exige a api 7 como minima, e nao a 11 como eu afirmei.

Comment: Não tem jeito, vou ter que criar outra então, certo? Entendo, obrigado por toda ajuda, meu caro.

Comment: @RodrigoP. me equivoquei, a api minima é 7. Provavelmente você está usando outro recurso que exige a 11 como minima, não é devida a classe appcompat.

Comment: Isso é bem estranho. Eu criei o projeto com a API minima em 16. Não sei ao certo qual o motivo deste erro de API.

Comment: @RodrigoP. sugiro que você crie outra pergunta a respeito da api do seu projeto e da que a ide está exigindo, adicionando tambem seu arquivo xml de configuracao do app, assim fica mais facil da galera aqui te ajudar.  e não se esqueça de fechar esta pergunta como resolvida.

Comment: Certo. Mais uma vez, muito obrigado.